# How can I test whether the output from a command is null or empty string?

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, subversion

I'm trying to get a pre-commit hook script to work on our old SVN box.
It's very old, running Ubuntu Server 8.04.

This script:
    @echo off
    ::
    :: Stops commits that have empty log messages.
    ::

```
@echo off

setlocal

rem Subversion sends through the path to the repository and transaction id
set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

rem check for an empty log message
svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr . > nul
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else exit 0

:err
echo. 1>&2
echo Your commit has been blocked because you didn't give any log message 1>&2
echo Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and 1>&2
echo then try committing again. -- Thank you 1>&2
exit 1
```

I think it's not working because the command findstr does not exist.
What does work is this:

```
if [[ -n "" ]] ; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

So I changed the script to:

```
@echo off
::
:: Stops commits that have empty log messages.
::

@echo off

setlocal

rem Subversion sends through the path to the repository and transaction id
set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

rem check for an empty log message
::svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr . > nul
::if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else (goto exitgood)

::svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr . > ""
::if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else (goto exitgood)

SET LOG=`svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN%`

if [[ -n %LOG%  ]]; then
        (goto exitgood)
else
        (goto err)
fi

:err
echo. 1>&2
echo Your commit has been blocked because you didn't give any log message 1>&2
echo Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and 1>&2
echo then try committing again. -- Thank you 1>&2
exit 1

:exitgood
exit 0
```

But that doesn't work either, they both exit with code 255.
Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Eh? These are `cmd.exe` batch scripts. What are they doing on your Linux box?

Comment: Good point. I forgot SVN runs on windows as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are batch scripts – as in MS Windows Batch. 
[FINDSTR](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php) was introduced in the Windows NT 4 Resource Kit.

`::` and `rem` are comments. (Or `::` is actually a label with *invalid* name).

You could probably run them under `wine` `cmd`, but would be better to port them to some native script (perl, python, bash, etc.).

Simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to print usage and exit
usage()
{
    printf "Usage: %s [repository] [transaction_id]\n" $(basename "$1") >&2
    exit 1
}

# Check that we have at least 2 arguments
[ $# -ge 2 ] || usage

repo="$2"
trans_id="$2"

# Check that command succeed, and set variable "msg" to output
if ! msg="$(svnlook log "$repo" -t "$trans_id")"; then
    printf "Check path and id.\n" >&2
    usage
fi

# If msg is empty
if [ "$msg" = "" ]; then
    printf \
"Your commit has been blocked because you didn't give any log message
Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and
then try committing again. -- Thank you.\n" >&2
     exit 2    
fi

# Else default exit AKA 0
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I though they looked familiar. I just associate SVN with Linux so it never occurred to me.

Comment: It happens. We learn trough repetition :). If you haven't used batch scripting (enough to recognize it) it isn't that big of a leap to miss.

Comment: Actually I've done fairly epic amounts of Windows batch scripting, it's Linux scripting I've done almost none of, beyond putting 1 or 2 commands in a text file and setting it to executable. Thanks for the example! Once upon a time I new how to add something that caused each line of the script to be dumped to stdout when executed. Something to so with adding X to the first line. Any idea what that is?

Comment: @RoboJ1M: You could add `-x` at prompt or in script for debug mode. For whole script e.g. `#!/bin/bash -x`, or `set -x`, for dump use `-v`. [More here.](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)